# Running Python scripts in linux

Tags: linux, shell, python, scripting

I'm trying to run Python scripts with a shebang on Ubuntu. When I create a python script

```
    #! /usr/bin/env python
    import sys
```

... and run it I get a shell error:

```
    root@host:/home/user# ./test.py
    : No such file or directory
```

How can I make it work?

**Solution**: Remove '\r's from line endings with dos2unix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I assume the script is executable? Also, check for carriage returns -- maybe windows got its dirty little hands on it?  You can check this with 'cat -vE test.py' and look for '\r'.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have windows line endings on your file. Please try running **dos2unix** on it.

Comment: Yes, it was line endings, I used vi, I'm sure dos2unix would work too.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the space between #! and /usr/bin/env, though I don't get why that would work when not importing packages...

Comment: You are right, I checked, it also does not work when not importing.

Comment: It also won't start with no space.

Answer (score 0):

Are you *sure* that the error is happening for the reason you think? Or are you (later in the script) trying to open a file? Start with the simplest case to get things working...

hello.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print "Hello, world"
```

then...

```
$ chmod +x hello.py
$ ./hello.py
Hello, world
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below one liners to remove the new line characters.

> perl -e 's/\r//g' -w -p -i  test.py

or

> sed -e "s/^M//" test.py > test_new.py